# In which of the following cases is there no continuous function $f$ from the set $S$ onto the set $T$?

Tags: continuity

In which of the following cases is there no continuous function $f$ from the set $S$ onto the set $T$?

1. $S=[0,1],T=\Bbb R$
2. $S=(0,1),T=\Bbb R$
3. $S=(0,1),T=(0,1]$
4. $S=\Bbb R,T=(0,1)$
   how we solve it.plz explain

Comment: You really need to figure out how to switch off caps lock.

Comment: People generally interpret all capitals as SHOUTING; it’s not a good idea.

Comment: Do you have *any* insight, idea, work done...in these? Say, compact sets are mapped to compact sets by cont. functions?

Answer (score 2):

HINTS:

1. Continuous functions take compact sets to compact sets.
2. It’s not hard to find a homeomorphism; you could start by thinking about the function $f(x)=\tan x$ and then modifying it a bit.
3. Fold $S$ in the middle and then stretch it by a factor of $2$.
4. If you’ve done (2), this one is easy.

Comment: I especially like the nice geometric view of number 3.